# ORACLE Import large spatial data using sqlplus

Tags: import, oracle-spatial

I have a script that contains several SQL statements. One of its columns has large data. It contains data from a SDO_GEOMETRY type. When a try to run the script from sqlplus, I got this error:

> Error 45 initializing SQL*Plus Internal error

Comment: Known Bug [3039738.] The only workaround, until bug is fixed, is to copy the SQL script file to a local disk (in case of Linux, a ext3 filesystem). (not GIS related)

Comment: In may case, the script is inside a docker container running an Linux instance. Still does not work.